Reverse Doob’s maximal inequality for bounded martingales
Consider the set of discrete or continuous time $L^\infty$-bounded martingales $X$ with $X_0 = 0$ almost surely. Here $L^\infty$-bounded means $\|X\|_{\infty} := \sup_t \mathbb \|X_t\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} < \infty$.
Does there exist some deterministic $C: \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R_+$ depending only on $\|X\|_{\infty}$ such that for all $T > 0$, and $0 < s < \|X_T\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$ we have
$$\mathbb P(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} X_t \geq s) \geq C_s \mathbb E[|X_T|]?$$

Since the right hand side may exceed 1, this doesn't make sense as stated.

@AnthonyQuas You are right, I probably need an a priori bound on the $L^1$ norm too…

Even if you add the condition that $|X_T|_1=1$, you still have no hope: you can define $X_t=0$ for all $t<T$ and $X_T=\pm N$ with probability $\frac1{2N}$, and 0 with probability $1-\frac 1N$. Doing this, the right hand side is $C_s$ for any value of $N$, but the left side is $\frac 1{2N}$.

@AnthonyQuas yep… last try, what about an a priori $L^\infty (\Omega)$ bound?

Try $X_T=\pm s$ with probability $\frac 12p$, $\pm \frac 12s$ with probability $\frac 12(1-p)$. All other $X_t$'s are 0. As $p\to 0$, the right side tends to $sC_s/2$ while the left side tends to 0.

@Anthony Quas And you are spot on… if you would like to write that as an answer I will accept it :sad:

No. Let $X_T$ be $\pm s$ with probability $\frac 12p$ and let $X_T$ be $\pm \frac 12s$ with probability $\frac 12(1-p)$. All other $X_t$'s are 0. As $p\to 0$, the right side tends to $sC_s/2$ while the left side tends to 0.
